# Doctrine2 query with QueryBuilder returns array instead of object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I want to get doctrin2 query result in object format but it gives me in array format.
I tried but I can't succeed.

This is demo query but if I want to apply similar types of join in another query than also requires results in object format but in all of them.

Can you have any solution?

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder("u")
->select("u.id as userid, up.id as profileid, u.username, u.email, u.isactive, up.firstname, up.lastname, up.profileimage, up.address, up.zipcode, up.biography")
->innerjoin("u.userprofile", "up")
->where("u.id = :userid")
->setParameter(":userid", $userid)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

ResultSet :

```
Array
(
    [userid] => 4
    [profileid] => 3
    [username] => Test user
    [email] => testuser@yahoo.com
    [isactive] => 1
    [firstname] => MyFname
    [lastname] => MyLname
    [profileimage] => 5111ea998c9476c2231180050d5ad64dc3298fe0.jpeg
    [address] => My Address
    [zipcode] => 36102555
    [biography] => This is my first symfon2.3 project.
)
```

Answer (score 3):

May be it's because you 're not loading the object fully, as you're loading it partially. That's why ORM is converting it automatically. You can use `partial` keyword [to force](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html) it to load as partial object, but be carefull.

Comment: Thank you Xurshid, But can you give me example I try to found from google but can't understand.

Comment: `->select(['partial u.{id,...}'])` - something like this.. I've never tried it, as it's not recommended by ORM.. You should better load it as full object..

Comment: Thanks I have done it. Xurshid29 Can You help me my another issue which is bit more complex about custom authentication provider.

Comment: Xurshid It requires to wait 90 minutes. I really appreciate your response and answer.

Comment: @Dipakchavda The answer to your question will be very long, It's not good to post an unrelated answer to this question.. Did you look at this [doc page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)?

Comment: Yes Xurshid, I have post actual issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774616/doctrine2-find-query-returns-user-value-not-from-database-but-fetch-from-custo